# Oracle: How to gather stats in a logical standby database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, performance, statistics, dataguard, query-performance

I have a Primary and a (logical) Standby Database. The Schema 'APP' gets synced.
Now a User has performance issues running a query against some tables in this 'APP' schema of the Standby Database. On the Primary the same query executed well after gathering table (DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS) stats.

How to refresh statistics on the standby-side? The DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS gives a [ORA-16224](http://ora-16224.ora-code.com/).

With

```
SELECT table_name,last_analyzed FROM dba_tables WHERE table_name IN ('TAB1','TAB2');
```

I can clearly see that the standby stats are a bit too old ;)

```
SELECT guard_status FROM v$database;

GUARD_STATUS
------------
STANDBY
```

Comment: What user did you connect with/as to run the stats? (There's DML that needs to run to store the statistics, not sure exactly what "class" of users are allowed to do that on a logical standby.)

Comment: Hi, I connect as SYSTEM through a proxy user.

Comment: Thanks Mat, you pointed me in the right direction, it's indeed a user and permission issue. On the primary the SYSTEM user is also able to gather stats. In the logical standby the only user who can gather stats in synced schemas is SYS. Please make a answer to earn your points ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run any DML in a logical standby database unless you deactivate, temporary, the guard feature. To overcome you isse you can do:

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE GUARD NONE;
SQL> SELECT GUARD_STATUS FROM V$DATABASE; 
GUARD_STATUS 
-------------------- 
NONE
```

And then run your dbms_stats.